# How to hide records, rather than delete them (soft delete from scratch)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's keep this simple. Let's say I have a `User` model and a `Post` model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    # id:integer name:string deleted:boolean

    has_many :posts       
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    # id:integer user_id:integer content:string deleted:boolean

    belongs_to :user
end
```

Now, let's say an admin wants to "delete" (hide) a post. So basically he, through the system, sets a post's `deleted` attribute to `1`. How should I now display this post in the view? Should I create a virtual attribute on the post like this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    # id:integer user_id:integer content:string deleted:boolean

    belongs_to :user

    def administrated_content
       if !self.deleted
          self.content
       else
          "This post has been removed"
       end
    end
end
```

While that would work, I want to implement the above in a large number of models, and I can't help feeling that copy+pasting the above comparative into all of my models could be DRYer. A lot dryer.

**I also think putting a `deleted` column in every single deletable model in my app feels a bit cumbersome too. I feel I should have a 'state' table. What are your thoughts on this:**

```
class State
    #id:integer #deleted:boolean #deleted_by:integer

    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :post
end
```

and then querying `self.state.deleted` in the comparator? Would this require a polymorphic table? I've only attempted polymorphic once and I couldn't get it to work. (it was on a pretty complex self-referential model, mind). And this still doesn't address the problem of having a very, very similar class method in my models to check if an instance is deleted or not before displaying content.

In the `deleted_by` attribute, I'm thinking of placing the admin's id who deleted it. But what about when an admin undelete a post? Maybe I should just have an `edited_by` id.

**How do I set up a `dependent: :destroy` type relationship between the user and his posts? Because now I want to do this: `dependent: :set_deleted_to_0` and I'm not sure how to do this.**

Also, we don't simply want to set the post's deleted attributes to 1, because we actually want to change the message our `administrated_content` gives out. We now want it to say, `This post has been removed because of its user has been deleted`. I'm sure I could jump in and do something hacky, but I want to do it properly from the start.

I also try to avoid gems when I can because I feel I'm missing out on learning.

Comment: I usually use a field `deleted_at` which is a datetime field. When this field is completed, it means this record is deleted (acts like a boolean but provides a date)

Comment: Have a look at paranoia gem -> https://github.com/radar/paranoia

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I usually use a field named `deleted_at` for this case:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :not_deleted, lambda { where(deleted_at: nil) }
  scope :deleted, lambda { where("#{self.table_name}.deleted_at IS NOT NULL") }

  def destroy
    self.update(deleted_at: DateTime.current)
  end

  def delete
    destroy
  end

  def deleted?
    self.deleted_at.present?
  end
  # ...
```

---

## Want to share this functionnality between multiple models?

## => Make an extension of it!

```
# lib/extensions/act_as_fake_deletable.rb
module ActAsFakeDeletable
  # override the model actions
  def destroy
    self.update(deleted_at: DateTime.current)
  end

  def delete
    self.destroy
  end

  def undestroy # to "restore" the file
    self.update(deleted_at: nil)
  end

  def undelete
    self.undestroy
  end
  
  # define new scopes
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      scope :destroyed, where("#{self.table_name}.deleted_at IS NOT NULL")
      scope :not_destroyed, where(deleted_at: nil)
      scope :deleted, lambda { destroyed }
      scope :not_deleted, lambda { not_destroyed }
    end
  end
end

class ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.act_as_fake_deletable(options = {})
    alias_method :destroy!, :destroy
    alias_method :delete!, :delete
    include ActAsFakeDeletable

    options = { field_to_hide: :content, message_to_show_instead: "This content has been deleted" }.merge!(options)

    define_method options[:field_to_hide].to_sym do
      return options[:message_to_show_instead] if self.deleted_at.present?
      self.read_attribute options[:field_to_hide].to_sym
    end
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  act_as_fake_deletable
```

Overwriting the defaults:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  act_as_fake_deletable field_to_hide: :title, message_to_show_instead: "This book has been deleted man, sorry!"
```

Boom! Done.

**Warning**: This module overwrite the ActiveRecord's `destroy` and `delete` methods, which means you won't be able to destroy your record using those methods anymore. Instead of overwriting you could create a new method, named `soft_destroy` for example. So in your app (or console), you would use `soft_destroy` when relevant and use the `destroy`/`delete` methods when you really want to "hard destroy" the record.

Comment: If OP needs this in a lot of models like implied in the post, a concern would be a good place for this.

Comment: @MichaelKohl I would like an example of this

Comment: I updated my answer with a module @Starkers for example

Comment: Okay that's pretty cool but I don't want to use a scope to not load the deleted records. I want to show the record, but change the content of what is shown. So normally 'self.content' would be shown, but now `'this has been deleted by admin x'` would be shown. How could I write that as a module? I'd have to say what attribute I wanted to overwrite.

Comment: Also, why do I need to place `act_as_fake_deletable` in my models when the ActiveRecord::Base is being extended to include the module already (third line up from the bottom - btw I've only had a breif foray with modules!)?

Comment: You need to add the `act_as_fake_deletable` because not ALL your models will inherit from this functionnality, and you will also need to create the deleted_at columns. You are not forced to use the scopes you know, just calling `YourModel.scoped` will return every instance, whatever the value of the deleted_at. Im gonna update my answer with methods to show a msg instead of actual content ;)

Comment: @Starkers I just updated my answer (with a `define_method`), but I can't test it right now, there might be some symtax errors ...