# Update a relation in a scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

How can I have something like an ActiveRecord `scope` that modifies the relation it's acting on?

Specifically, I want to be able to do this:

```
Model.some_scope.fake_destroy_all
```

Where `fake_destroy_all` is the functionality I'm trying to create.  It'll be pretty much equivalent to `.update_all(deleted: true)`.

A weak alternative would be:

```
def fake_destroy_all(relation = Model)
    relation.update_all(deleted: true)
end

#...

Model.fake_destroy_all(Model.some_scope)
```

But that's not ideal.  What I'd like to do is something like:

```
scope :fake_destroy_all, update_all(deleted: true)
```

But that doesn't work.

Is it possible to do something like what I'm describing?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23017070/how-to-hide-records-rather-than-delete-them-soft-delete-from-scratch/23017174#23017174

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
def self.fake_destroy_all
  self.update_all(deleted: true)
end
```

It turns out that relations retain all the class methods. Scopes are class methods as well, and it's the exact mechanism that allows scopes to be "chained".

Therefore, relations with this model will also have this method with `self` being an instance of a relation.

The scope syntax can probably be fixed like so (cannot test right now, but note the lambda instead of simple method call):

```
scope :fake_destroy_all, -> { update_all(deleted: true) }
```

I suppose, **without updating inside a lambda** it effectively calls this method on invoking `scope`, on class definition. It does work with simple `where`-type scopes because **`where` has no side-effect**, it only returns an applicable filter. It's evaluated once and saved in a method for use in the future as-is.

**With a lambda**, however, the execution is held until the scope is actually applied, not until defined. It's necessary, because `update_all` does have **a side-effect**.

The same trick is useful if you are specifying a scope with a constantly changing condition, the simplest case being dependency on `Time.now`, that changes over time and needs to be re-evaluated each time.

However, I suggest you use a class method: a scope is more like a filter, whereas this is more like a "filter enforcement". While this might work too, scopes are semantically for different use cases.