# Rails 4+ Best practices: Delete parent while keeping children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to keep child records and the hierarchy, even when the parent is deleted. I see two options:

1. Keep the existing parent and utilize a "deleted_at" field to indicate the
   parent itself is inactive, but the relationship still exists. This will lead to a number of effectively dead parent records being stored forever. Meh.
2. Assign all abandoned child records to a generic "collector" zombie parent record. I prefer this, but then you lose the history to the original source of the child record.

I don't have the Rails experience to see ahead as to which of these 2 would be the most advisable path to take, or maybe there's an altogether different solution.

SO is telling me this appears to be a subjective question and they may close it. I hope not, because I'm sure this is a question that others have as well.

Comment: You can take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23017070/how-to-hide-records-rather-than-delete-them-soft-delete-from-scratch/23017174#23017174

Comment: This also may be interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/378331/physical-vs-logical-soft-delete-of-database-record

Comment: Thanks guys. Those are both relevant references, and helpful. It does seem like best practice is to go with the soft delete over the hard delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me like you're basically asking about "soft delete" functionality. When I want this kind of behavior, I usually add an `active` attribute that defaults to `true`. I also add an `active` scope to the model so I can do something like `Salon.active` to conveniently get everything that's active.

So I guess my answer is that I'd do something like #1, which I would call a soft delete. Idea #2 seems pretty crazy to me.

Comment: Thanks! It indeed looks like the soft delete is the best-practices way to go.