# Rails 4 - Keep child records with belongs_to many models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

On Rails 4.

I have a `Rental` model which `belongs_to :house` and `belongs_to :user`

When a user destroys his/her account, the rentals associated with the user are being destroyed, although they are also still associated with a house.

What is the best way to go about keeping the rentals regardless of the user associated with the rental being destroyed? That way `@house.rentals` can still be viewed, but simply won't have a user object anymore.

I am not declaring `dependent: :destroy`, so I thought this would be default behavior, but it is not.

thx!

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28568050/rails-4-best-practices-delete-parent-while-keeping-children) and could you change destroying the account to instead de-activating it? Or, can you do a `@user.delete` instead of `@user.destroy` to avoid destroying the child records (assuming you don't have foreign keys)?