# Rails 5 dependent: :destroy doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following classes:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product_category

  def destroy
    puts "Product Destroy!"
  end

end

class ProductCategory < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products, dependent: :destroy

  def destroy
    puts "Category Destroy!"
  end
end
```

Here, I am trying to override the destroy method where I eventually want to do this:

```
update_attribute(:deleted_at, Time.now)
```

When I run the following statement in Rails console: `ProductCategory.destroy_all` I get the following output

```
Category Destroy!
Category Destroy!
Category Destroy!
```

Note: I have three categories and each category has more than one Products. I can confirm it by `ProductCategory.find(1).products`, which returns an array of products. I have heard the implementation is changed in Rails 5. Any points on how I can get this to work?

**EDIT**

What I eventually want is, to soft delete a category and all associated products in one go. Is this possible? Or will ave to iterate on every Product object in a before destroy callback? (Last option for me)

Comment: Remove both of your destroy methods and try it again.

Comment: It looks to me that you're overiding active_model destroy method, and that you should call "super" in destroy?

Comment: I really don't suggest overwriting ActiveRecord methods. make your own like `update_as_destroyed` and `update_as_destroyed_all` instead of overwriting existing ones.

Comment: Sounds like you want "soft delete". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23017070/how-to-hide-records-rather-than-delete-them-soft-delete-from-scratch

Comment: Yes, I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is how I did it in the end:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product_category

  def destroy
    run_callbacks :destroy do
      update_attribute(:deleted_at, Time.now)
      # return true to escape exception being raised for rollback
      true
    end
  end

end

class ProductCategory < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products, dependent: :destroy

  def destroy
    # run all callback around the destory method
    run_callbacks :destroy do
      update_attribute(:deleted_at, Time.now)
      # return true to escape exception being raised for rollback
      true
    end
  end
end
```

I am returning true from the destroy does make update_attribute a little dangerous but I am catching exceptions at the ApplicationController level as well, so works well for us.

Answer (score 1):

You should call super from your destroy method:

```
def destroy
  super 
  puts "Category destroy"
end
```

But I definitely wouldn't suggest that you overide active model methods.

Comment: from his question it would not work, because the record would still be destroyed. He doesn't want that

Comment: Yes, that's what he wants to do, but my answer is referring to his question that is why dependent: :destroy does not work. He is not asking how to implement update that he wants to do.