# Hide records rather than delete them in ruby on rails 4.2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to hide some of the records of the statement rather than deleting them completely in order to retrieve the respective balance amount after the temporary hide.

Please refer the screenshot for better understanding as shown below;

[image: screenshot.png]

How would I proceed?

index.html.erb

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">

        <div class="table-responsive myTable">

            <table id = "kola" class="table listing text-center">
                <tr class="tr-head">
                    <td>Date</td>
                    <td>Description</td>
                    <td>Amount</td>
                    <td>Discount</td>
                    <td>Paid</td>
                    <td>Balance</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>


                <a href="#" class="toggle-formed" style="float: right;" >Search</a>

                <div id="sample">

                    <%= form_tag xvaziris_path, remote: true, method: :get, class: "form-group", role: "search" do %>
                    <p>
                        <center><%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search for.....", autofocus: true, class: "form-control-search" %>
                            <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil, class: "btn btn-md btn-primary" %></center>
                        </p>
                        <% end %><br>
                    </div>



                    <%= render @xvaziris %>

                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

_xvaziri.html.erb

```
<tr   class="tr-<%= cycle('odd', 'even') %>">

    <td class="col-1"><%= xvaziri.date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') %></td>
    <td class="col-3"><%= span_with_possibly_red_color xvaziri.description %></td>


    <td class="col-1"><%= number_with_precision(xvaziri.amount, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>

    <td class="col-1 neg"><%= number_with_precision(xvaziri.discount, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>

    <td class="col-1 neg"><%= number_with_precision(xvaziri.paid, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>


    <% @balance += xvaziri.amount.to_f - xvaziri.discount.to_f - xvaziri.paid.to_f %>

    <% color = @balance >= 0 ? "pos" : "neg" %>

    <td class="col-1 <%= color %>"><%= number_with_precision(@balance.abs, :delimiter => ",", :precision => 2) %></td>

</tr>
```

xvaziri.rb

```
class Xvaziri < ActiveRecord::Base

    def to_s
        description
    end

    def self.import(file)
        CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
            Xvaziri.create! row.to_hash
        end
    end


    def self.search(search)

        where (["description LIKE ? OR amount LIKE ? OR paid LIKE ?", "%#{search}%","%#{search}%","%#{search}%"]) 

    end

end
```

20151128091020_create_xvaziris.rb

```
class CreateXvaziris < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        create_table :xvaziris do |t|
            t.date :date
            t.text :description
            t.decimal :amount
            t.decimal :discount
            t.decimal :paid
            t.decimal :balance
            t.timestamps null: false
        end
    end
end
```

xvaziris_controller.rb

```
class XvazirisController < ApplicationController

    before_action :set_xvaziri, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

     layout "fedena"


    def index
        @xvaziris = Xvaziri.search(params[:search])


        respond_to do |format|
            format.js
            format.html 
        end 
    end

    def import
        Xvaziri.import(params[:file])
        redirect_to xvaziris_url, notice: "Xvaziris imported."
    end

    def show
    end

    def new
        @xvaziri = Xvaziri.new
    end

    def create
        @xvaziri = Xvaziri.new(xvaziri)
        if
            @xvaziri.save
            flash[:notice] = 'Xvaziri Created'
            redirect_to @xvaziri
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
        if @xvaziri.update(xvaziri)
            flash[:notice] = 'Xvaziri Updated'
            redirect_to @xvaziri
        else
            render 'edit'
        end

    end

    def destroy
        @xvaziri.destroy
        flash[:notice] = 'Xvaziri was successfully destroyed.'
        redirect_to xvaziris_url    
    end

    private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_xvaziri
        @xvaziri = Xvaziri.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def xvaziri
        params.require(:xvaziri).permit(:date, :description, :amount, :discount, :paid)
    end

end
```

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can add boolean field and after clicking on delete just update attribute to true and in your loop just display false records

Comment: Thanks for the reply.How do I do it practically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a practical help for adding the hidden field:

Add a migration with typing this in your console:

```
rails g migration AddHiddenToXvaziris hidden:boolean
```

Open the generated migration file and change the following line:

```
add_column :xvaziris, :hidden, :boolean, :default => false
```

Save the file und run the migration:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Then you have to check whether the hidden-attribute is false and add a row to `@xvaziris` only if hidden is false. In your *xvaziris_controller.rb* simply change the index method like this:

```
def index
    @xvaziris = Xvaziri.find_by hidden: false
    @xvaziris = @xvaziri.search(params[:search])

    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
        format.html 
    end 
end
```

You also have to set the hidden attribute to true when the destroy action is called.
in your *xvaziris_controller.rb* change the destroy method:

```
def destroy
    @xvaziri = Xvaziri.find(params[:id])
    @xvaziri.hidden = true
    flash[:notice] = 'Xvaziri was successfully hidden.'
    redirect_to xvaziris_url    
end
```

---

*Note, that elements aren't destroyed now, but are set to hidden == true.
In case you want elements to be destroyed elsewhere, I recommend to leave the destroy method as it is and add a new method in your* xvaziris_controller.rb:

```
def hide_xvaziri
    @xvaziri = Xvaziri.find(params[:id])
    @xvaziri.hidden = true
    flash[:notice] = 'Xvaziri was successfully hidden.'
    redirect_to xvaziris_url    
end
```

*When you do so you also have to add the following line in your routes:*

```
get '/xvaziri/:id/hide', to: 'xvaziris#hide_xvaziri'
```

*You can customize the route, if you want, to fit your needs.*

---

To show the hidden elements up again I recommend to do the following:
Add a "Show all"-Button to your *index.html.erb*:

```
<%= link_to "Show all", resetfilter_xvaziri_path %>
```

Then you must add to you *routes.rb* this line:

```
get '/xvaziri/resetfilter', to: 'xvaziris#reset_filter'
```

In your *xvaziris_controller.rb* at this method:

```
def reset_filter
    xvaziris = Xvaziri.all // or do the search here, depending on what you need
    xvaziris.each do |xvaziri|
        xvaziri.hidden = false
    end
    redirect_to xvaziris_url
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I have added the controller code

Comment: I have added the further explanation

Comment: Did that help you with your problem?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just want to disregard that respective invoice while calculating the balance and again bring it back in the same place (i.e., within one query) or any other way? Is your solution does the same thing?

Comment: And do you want the hided invoices to be considered in the balance calculation?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just for couple of minutes, and when I hid the invoices, I don't want to consider it in balance calculation and for the same purpose I want to hide the invoices.Hope you understand the matter.

Comment: Ok then my code fits partially your needs. While calculating, only the invoices are considered, that are not hidden. To replace the invoices and show all of them I recommend to show up a button "Reset filter" or "Show all" which changes all hidden == true values to false. Do you need help for that?

Comment: Thanks. But how will I hide that respective invoice through button or what?

Comment: That's up to you. Button click might be the simplest way. just add another link_to element witch points to the destroy or hide_xvaziri method

Comment: I didn't get this point what you mentioned before :                                      In your xvaziris_controller.rb simply add one line und change the second one:

Comment: I changed the method in my edit and missed to change the describing text to. I'm sorry. I'll update it.

Comment: Thanks again.Get back to you later.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117174/discussion-between-muhammad-yaseen-and-michael-l).

Comment: Mr.Michael, Where are you? I am following your way of approach and stuck up in the middle, would be much better if we clear the way to reach the destination.As I need this solution most importantly.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: This answer is invalid as it assumes that the OP wants to permanently archive records.

## Use scopes

1. Add a new field `archived` to your table in the usual way. I assume you know how to do that.
2. Instead of deleting rows, set `some_xvaziri.archived=true` to flag the record(s) you do not want to show anymore.
3. In your model, add a "default scope" (see http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/default_scope/class )

   ```
   class Xvaziri < ActiveRecord::Base
     default_scope { where(:archived => false) }
   end
   ```

   This will remove those records from all rails queries (unless you explicitely tell rails to ignore the default scope for a query).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For your kind information, I don't want to delete any record but temporarily remove them from the calculation and bring it back again at the same place.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What do you want to do?

Comment: Thanks. Actually in the screen-shot I explicitly highlighted one row containing inv # 7072, I want to take it away and find the balance without inv #7072 and again I have to leave it as before.

Comment: Yes, so much is clear. Do you want to have the "taking away" persist in the DB for an hour or a few days or something like that? Or just disregard it while calculating the balance (i.e., within one query)?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, just disregard it while calculating the balance (i.e., within one query)?

Answer (score 1):

You can introduce new field `hidden` that is by default `false`, so all of your existing data will be shown. Then for every record you want to hide set this field(flag) to `true`.

Implement your methods for balance to include or exclude hidden records.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could please explain in detail as I am the newbie?

Comment: I just want to disregard the invoices amount while calculating the balance (i.e., within one query) or in any other way ? I introduced new field hidden that is by default false, but for every record how can I hide and set that field(flag) to true? Hope you understand the matter.

Comment: Mr.Nermin, Hope you are doing great! I tried with other coding but didn't get the result.How do I proceed for the desired results.Please guide..

Comment: Mr.Nermin, I will wait for your great solution.

Comment: I wanted it the most.

Comment: Mr.Nermin, I am waiting for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

Go through this  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23017070/how-to-hide-records-rather-than-delete-them-soft-delete-from-scratch)

ALso there is this gem act-as-paranoid which does the same thing

Comment: But How do I proceed with my data as I have only one model?